# Как убрать серый фон в input и textarea в Internet Exporer

Tags: css, input, internet-explorer, textarea

У меня для `input` и `textarea` есть собственные стили, убраны все лишние кнопки ***(стрелки, крестики, границы)***, и поставлен фон на чисто белый. Во всех браузерах он белый кроме Internet Explorer. Если текстовое поле пустое, то фон затемняется и оно становится серым; если я нажму на текстовое поле либо что-то туда введу, то снова белое. Как убрать это затемнение из Internet Explorer? Подойдут любые способы (css, javascript, jquery, html).

```css
.tex12ie {
  width: 517px;
  outline: none;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -khtml-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -o-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
  resize: none;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  -moz-transition: border .35s; 
  -webkit-transition: border .35s; 
  -o-transition: border .35s;
  transition: border .35s;
  border-radius: 5px;
      resize: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -khtml-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="tex12" maxlength="1000" class="tex12ie" spellcheck="false" name="message" placeholder="Сообщение для технической поддержки" style="box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 200px black; background: #fff; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; height: 200px; display: block; margin-left: 7px; margin-right: 7px"></textarea>
```

Comment: Задай внутреннюю тень белого цвета...

Comment: Как? Не знаю никакой тени

Answer (score 0):

Тут черная для наглядности... Поменяй цвет... Но учти что для `IE` ниже ***9*** версии не будет работать

```css
input {
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 20px black;
}
```

```html
<input />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89699/discussion-on-answer-by-air------input--textarea--internet-e).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что Internet Explorer неадекватно реагирует на opacity. Использовать только rgb.

```
:-webkit-placeholder {
    color: #676767 !important;
}

:-moz-placeholder { 
    color: #676767 !important;
}

:-khtml-placeholder {  
    color: #676767 !important;
}

:-ms-placeholder {  
    color: #676767 !important;
}

:-o-placeholder {  
    color: #676767 !important;
}

:placeholder {  
    color: #676767 !important;
}

::-webkit-placeholder {
    color: #676767 !important;
}

::-moz-placeholder { 
    color: #676767 !important;
}

::-khtml-placeholder {  
    color: #676767 !important;
}

::-ms-placeholder {  
    color: #676767 !important;
}

::-o-placeholder {  
    color: #676767 !important;
}

::placeholder {  
    color: #676767 !important;
}

:-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #676767 !important;
}

:-moz-input-placeholder { 
    color: #676767 !important;
}

:-khtml-input-placeholder {  
    color: #676767 !important;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: #676767 !important;
}

:-o-input-placeholder {  
    color: #676767 !important;
}

:input-placeholder {  
    color: #676767 !important;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #676767 !important;
}

::-moz-input-placeholder { 
    color: #676767 !important;
}

::-khtml-input-placeholder {  
    color: #676767 !important;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: #676767 !important;
}

::-o-input-placeholder {  
    color: #676767 !important;
}

::input-placeholder {  
    color: #676767 !important;
}
```

Comment: На дворе 21 век...

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нет совмещения с Internet Explorer